# Why can't I find the C:\ProgramData\Desktop folder?

Tags: windows

My `C:\programdata\desktop` folder has apparently gone missing.

How do I reinstall it, without doing a complete recovery? My Recycle Bin is empty and I know I would not have deleted this file.

Comment: Please move this to superuser.  Also, there is no such file as C:\programdata\desktop.  It should be in C:\Documents and Settings\\[your username]\Desktop for Windows XP.

Comment: There is such a folder in Vista/Windows 7: C:\ProgramData

Comment: Ahh, I love people who never look past XP :-). Although it makes me wonder what one would want to do in that folder; it's just a link to `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` here anyway.

Comment: If I navigate to C:\ProgramData\Desktop, the folder is empty.  Yet if I go to C:\Users\Public\Desktop, there are a number of shortcuts in there.  Something is screwy with Vista/7's virtual folders.

Answer (score 5):

I think that's a hidden folder.
2 ways of making it visible:

- Control Panel > Folder Options > View Tab > Select Show hidden folders.
- Just type in c:\ProgramData\Desktop in the commandbar on top of explorer. This should show the contents of the folder.

Comment: It's indeed a hidden folder, this trick should do it!

Answer (score 1):

and when it's gone.. go to an admin command prompt and type the following.

cd \programdata

mklink /j desktop c:\users\public\desktop

attrib +s +h desktop

this restores it.